# ValueAnimator behaviour changes when AdView shows in

Tags: android, view, admob, android-animation, android-custom-view

I've made a custom view for visualizes the progress. It has a simple intro animation like the below :

```
PropertyValuesHolder c=PropertyValuesHolder.ofInt("c",0,100);
ValueAnimator anim=new ValueAnimator();
anim.setValues(c);
anim.addUpdateListener(new ValueAnimator.AnimatorUpdateListener() {
      @Override
      public void onAnimationUpdate(ValueAnimator animation) {
          position = (int) animation.getAnimatedValue("c");
          postInvalidate();
      }
  });
anim.setDuration(1000);
anim.start();
```

It works smoothly with about 50 keyframes, but after the AdView that placed on the parent view, turns visible the same animation runs with lags (performance reduced to about 20 keyframes). I check the `ValueAnimator.FrameDelay`, it doesn't change.

[image: before adMob]
[image: after adMob]

What causes this problem, And what is the solution?

Comment: Hard to say for sure without seeing much more code, but my advice is to use the Android Studio profiled/debug tools to compare your layout with/without the ad (which is likely a WebView and may be taking a lot of CPU to render if it's not HW accelerated - just an idea -).

Comment: Another thing that occurred to me... In the device you're using to test, enable (in Developer tools) the "Debug GPU -> SHow Overdraw" (or similar) to see if the AD is causing a lot of overdraw; play with the various tools the device has to offer to see if you can pinpoint what is causing the slowness. The profiler is your friend! (also use Tools -> Layout inspector) to see a snapshot of your layout at runtime.

Comment: (btw, the widget looks cool) :)

Comment: @MartinMarconcini Thanks for the complete explanation, I've already checked but there is no enormous overload

Comment: @MartinMarconcini Thanks for your help, It works

Comment: Glad to hear it worked. Hit me up if you hit any other roadblocks, I had to design a very similar control once for a very _popular_ app (they still use it afaik) and though I cannot share the code (I don't think I even have it), it was an ... _enlightening_ experience... to be nice about it :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As [@MartinMarconcini](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2684/martin-marconcini) said, the problem related to the WebView that embedded inside the AdView. The performance improved by enabling Hardware Acceleration on the AdView.

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT) 
        adView.setLayerType(View.LAYER_TYPE_HARDWARE, null);
   else adView.setLayerType(View.LAYER_TYPE_SOFTWARE, null);
```